# Expose Date Filter instead of Start & End Dates

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I have a content type event with start and end dates marked. I have create a view with exposed filter, where in users can choose a date and see the event on those days. Right now, view is only allowing me to choose start and end dates. This way if an event is between March 1st - March 10th, there is no way for user to filter and see the events for say March 5th. Technically event being from 1st-10th is also present on March 5th. How can I expose a filter where in user can get events by any date.

Below is what I have now:
[image: Filter now]

But I want like below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to solve a similar problem: creating a membership list per a specific date (based on "membership date" field with start and optional end date elements). Here is my current solution - hope it helps!

Environment
 1. I use VIEWS, RELATIONS and the PARTIAL DATES module and added a partial dates range field type to the Relation between a person and the organisation. This allows multiple memberships and "fuzzy" start and end dates if exact data is unavailable (i.e. "member since 1995"). You can probably put the date range field directly on your event node, and you may be able to use the standard date field if you don't need to allow for "fuzzy" dates.
Note that the Partial date range field automatically calculates timestamp values for "from" and "to" dates.

In the view, I added 2 exposed filters
 - "partial_date_timestamp_to" >= selected date 
 - "partial_date" <= selected date
I also added 2 non-exposed filters to allow incomplete nodes to be shown (since membership data is not always perfect) you might not need this if your events always have complete, valid start and end dates.
So my filter criteria now reads: (partial_date_timestamp <= selected date OR partial_date_timestamp is empty) AND (partial_date_timestamp_to >= selected date OR partial_date_timestamp_to is empty)

It works, but entering the desired date in timestamp format isn't very user-friendly. Next step is to get desired date from user by a more comfortable method, then convert the result for the view filter.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [Date Picker Module](https://drupal.org/project/datepicker)

Once you download it, enable it, and clear your cache you should see a filter field that is called Date (node). From there it's pretty self explanatory.